# Difference between "MM" standing for Months and "mm" standing for minutes when using Format function

Tags: vba, date, excel, formatting

My issue is that I am trying to set up a rolling count since our last accident at work. The code below works in a fashion. The rolling count works fine, but there is a problem with removing the "s" from the words (hours, minutes, seconds ect) with the Month and Minute.

Here's my code:

```
Sub LTI_Sub()

Static etime

'Exit Sub ' Uncomment to Stop

etime = Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

Sheets("LTI").Range("Time") = LTI(Sheets("LTI").Range("Last"))

Application.OnTime etime, "LTI_Sub", , True


End Sub


Function LTI(LastLTI As Date)

x = Now() - LastLTI

Yx = Format(x, "yy")
If Yx = 1 Then
YS = ""
Else
YS = "s"
End If

Mx = Format(x, "mm")
If Mx = 1 Then
MS = ""
Else
MS = "s"
End If

Dx = Format(x, "DD")
If Dx = 1 Then
Ds = ""
Else
Ds = "s"
End If

Hx = Format(x, "HH")
If Hx = 1 Then
Hs = ""
Else
Hs = "s"
End If

MMx = Format(x, "MM")
If MMx = 1 Then
MMs = ""
Else
MMs = "s"
End If

Sx = Format(x, "SS")
If Sx = 1 Then
Ss = ""
Else
Ss = "s"
End If

LTI = Format(x, "YY \Y\e\a\r\" & YS & ", mm \M\o\n\t\h\" & MS & ", DD \D\a\y\" & Ds & "," & vbNewLine & "HH \H\o\u\r\" & Hs & ", MM \M\i\n\u\t\e\" & MMs & ", \A\n\d SS \S\e\c\o\n\d\" & Ss)

End Function
```

Now I'm not sure how VBA knows the difference between `mm` and `MM` when it comes to actually formatting the time, but on the lines where `Mx` and `MMx` are determined if the "s" is needed, it always treats it as a month value. How do I tell it to be minutes?

There's also a weird "fault" with the line `x = Now() - LastLTI` (where `LastLTI` is the date of the last accident). When returned in VBA it comes back with an extra month and day on it, but when done in Excel it returns the correct value. So for example, if it's been exactly 1 day since the lat accident (down to the second), VBA returns the following string: "00 Years, 01 Month, 02 Days, 00 Hours, 00 Minute , 00 Seconds" <-- Notice that the minutes has dropped the S because "Month" is equal to 1.

I hope this explains what I'm trying to achieve!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know about the issue you raise here, but another thing to consider is I don't think years will behave as you expect. For example, if I enter `? format(now()-(now()-1),"yy")` in the immediate window the result is 99, short for 1899. This makes sense since the Excel calendar begins on 12/31/1899 and `format(1,"yyyy-mm-dd")` evaluates to 1899-12-31.

Comment: If you don't have hours in the format string, 'mm' is always month. Why not use the Minute function instead?

Comment: I'm not familiar with term `rolling count.` Could someone shed light, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a few different date functions including [DateDiff](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/datediff.php) which returns the *difference* between two dates given to a specified interval, as well as `DateAdd` does the inverse of that by allowing you to *add* specified intervals to a date value. I also use the `TimeValue` function which returns only the *time* portion of the date.

I think this gets what you want, or at least should get you very very close.

```
Function LTI(LastLTI As Date)
Dim yx As Long
Dim mx As Long
Dim dx As Long
Dim hx As Long
Dim mmx As Long
Dim sx As Long
Dim ys As String
Dim ms As String
Dim ds As String
Dim hs As String
Dim mms As String
Dim ss As String

Dim dtNow As Date
dtNow = Now()

yx = DateDiff("yyyy", dtNow, LastLTI)
ys = IIf(yx = 1, "", "s")

mx = DateDiff("m", DateAdd("yyyy", yx, dtNow), LastLTI)
ms = IIf(mx = 1, "", "s")

dx = Format(dtNow - LastLTI, "dd")
ds = IIf(dx = 1, "", "s")

hx = DateDiff("h", TimeValue(dtNow), TimeValue(LastLTI))
hs = IIf(hx = 1, "", "s")

'compute the remaining minutes not allocated to a whole hour, above:
mmx = Format(TimeValue(dtNow), "n") - Format(TimeValue(LastLTI), "n")
mms = IIf(mmx = 1, "", "s")

' compute the remaining seconds not allocated to a whole minute, above:
sx = Format(TimeValue(dtNow), "ss") - Format(TimeValue(LastLTI), "ss")
ss = IIf(sx = 1, "", "s")

LTI = yx & "\Y\e\a\r\" & ys & ", " & _
        mx & "\M\o\n\t\h\" & ms & ", " & _
        dx & "\D\a\y\" & ds & "," & vbNewLine & _
        hx & "\H\o\u\r\" & hs & ", " & _
        mmx & "\M\i\n\u\t\e\" & mms & ", \A\n\d " & _
        sx & "\S\e\c\o\n\d\" & ss

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Did not know about `DateDiff`. Will take this approach in the future!

Comment: I had to make a few minor adjustments. Minutes and hours show as a minus value, so have multiplied by -1. Also, I removed the "\" from the text as these were only used when using `Format()` as a way of stopping VBA from treating a "m" in the string as `m` for month. Thanks very much, works great

Comment: There is also an error with your code on the `mmx` line: `mmx = DateDiff("n", DateAdd("h", hx, TimeValue(dtNow)), TimeValue(LastLTI))` should be `mmx = Format(TimeValue(dtNow), "n") - Format(TimeValue(LastLTI), "n")`. Otherwise the minutes roll over so 2 hours is 2 hours and 120mins. Thanks

Comment: @SilverShotBee oooh I thought I caught that with the `mmx = ` line I must not have pasted it correctly here. Good catch, though!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Format (expression, "mm")` for minutes, try `Format (expression, "n")`.